# prove by contradicition that there does not exist a constant $c$, such that for all integers $n \geq1$, $(n+1)^2 - n^2 < c$

Tags: inequality

First thing I did was simplify the above to $2n-1 < c$, from there I changed the simplified expression to $2n-1 \geq c$ and tried to make that contradict with $n \geq 1$. the problem being that I can't make them contradict. any help would be appreciated!

EDIT*
the above should say 2n+1 not 2n-1

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have decided that you need to find a contradiction between "$n\geq1$" and "$2n-1\geq c$", but that is not what's meant.

You are being asked to assume that there *is* a number $c$ such that $(n+1)^2-n^2<c$ no matter what $n$ is. And then from that assumption, reach a contradiction.

---

EDIT: I think I understand better what you are trying to do. If you continue to assume that there is a $c$ such that for all $n$, $2n-1<c$, then you need to find a *particular* $n$ that contradicts this assumption. So what about $n=\left\lceil\frac{c+1}{2}\right\rceil+1$?

Comment: yes, but how did you get that value?

Comment: It makes $2n-1>c$.

Comment: but where did it come from, you didn't randomly guess that and it worked. also , n must be >= 1. how do you know that n >= 1 is true ⌈(c+1)/2⌉+1?

Comment: Just solve $2n-1>c$ for $n$, and make sure that you end up with an integer using the ceiling operator. Also, if you are assuming such a $c$ exists, it would have to be positive for obvious reasons. Therefore $\left\lceil\frac{c+1}{2}\right\rceil$ is positive. And one more is greater than $1$.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped (see above edit). it should simplify to 2n+1, which makes things a little different, which is why I was confused. I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $x_n = (n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n + 1 \to +\infty$ as $n \to +\infty$ which means it is an unbounded sequence, so no such $c$ can exist.

Alternately, you can argue by graph. Draw the line $y = 2x + 1$ for $x \geq 1$ and see that the graph of the equation is a straight line extends beyond and above any horizontal line $y = c$.

Comment: I'm confused, could you elaborate? where did 2n+1→+∞ and n→+∞ come from?

Comment: I understand how it was simplified, I don't understand the why you added →+∞